# Is it possible to use lazy values within for-expressions?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I have a list of `Chicken`s and `Egg`s I want to create. They are defined as:

```
class Chicken (val name: String, e: => Egg) { lazy val child = e }

class Egg (val name: String, c: => Chicken) { lazy val parent = c }
```

and a single pair must be instantiated lazily because they contain circular references:

```
  def fillBarn {
    lazy val chicken: Chicken = new Chicken("abc", egg)
    lazy val egg: Egg = new Egg("def", chicken)
  }
```

I have a list of chicken / egg names that I want to create. Unfortunately the following doesn't compile:

```
val names = List("C1 E1", "C2 E2", "C3 E3")
val list = for {
  Array(cn, en) <- names.map(_.split(" "))
  lazy c: Chicken = new Chicken(cn, e)
  lazy e: Egg = new Egg(en, c)
} yield (c, e)
```

but it does without the sugar:

```
val list = names.map(_.split(" ")).map { 
  case Array(cn, en) => 
    lazy val c: Chicken = new Chicken(cn, e)
    lazy val e: Egg = new Egg(en, c)
    (c, e)
}
```

Now arguably in this simple case it's nicer without the for-expression, but if I did want to use the for-expression, could I?

I also realise that in this trivial case I could construct the `Chicken` and `Egg` instances within a `yield` block, but this won't generally be true, say if I wanted to do some extra filtering and mapping based on the instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in this (and arguably also in more advanced cases), you could always adapt the `fillBarn` method to give you exactly what you need (that’s the only way to make sense of this method anyway):

```
def fillBarn(c: String, e: String) = {
  lazy val chicken: Chicken = new Chicken(c, egg)
  lazy val egg: Egg = new Egg(e, chicken)
  (chicken, egg)
}
```

and then

```
val list = for {
  Array(cn, en) <- names.map(_.split(" "))
  (c, e) = fillBarn(cn, en)
} yield (c, e)
```

Of course, if you want to, there is no need in defining the `fillBarn` method. You can also do it in-line:

```
val list = for {
  Array(cn, en) <- names.map(_.split(" "))
  (c, e) = {
    lazy val chicken: Chicken = new Chicken(cn, egg)
    lazy val egg: Egg = new Egg(en, chicken)
    (chicken, egg)
  }
} yield (c, e)
```

The general structure of a `for` statement in Scala is fixed. There is only the `flatMap`/`map`/`foreach` with `<-` or the direct assignment to a new variable name for later use with `=`. But on the right side of these statements you may put whatever you like inside a block as long as this block returns the appropriate object.

Comment: Great! Thanks very much. I think the in-line pattern is what I'm looking for (the fillBarn method here was just showing that they need lazy instantiation, but having a separate factory method would certainly be appropriate sometimes).